# Text pagination for ebook reader on Windows 10 project (UWP)

Tags: c#, pagination, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, ebook-reader

I'm trying to make a reader app for Windows 10 and stuck with the pagination problem. While searching for some solutions I found projects for WPF and Windows 8 Silverlight, but it seems that in UWP some of needed namespaces, classes etc just missing.

So, I tried to use RichTextBlock with ContentOverflow option and build entire book at once. But this method for a large book is really slow, so it seems I need to find another way.

Another possible solution is to use font metrics to calculate how many words can fit, but FontFamily class doesn't contain any similar fields for that.

Comment: I have no answer. But - if you did not find solution, maybe this can provide you information how paging (in kindle) works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kzdugwr4Fgk

Answer (score 0):

Your approach worked for me, and it was pretty fast - small books (< 4mb) was processed and displayed in wery short time, up to 3 seconds. Maybe you should try this way one more time? I used recursive way to parse book and transform all elements into UI elements (like Paragraph) etc.